# Por que a Borda só afasta o elemento Horizontalmente e não Verticalmente?

Tags: html, css, css-border

Porque a Borda no `<span>` só afasta o elemento lateralmente, porém verticalmente a borda fica para fora do *container* pai?

Repare nesse exemplo abaixo que quando eu uso a borda no `<span>` ela não fica para fora a esquerda da `div`, porém no top da `div` a borda fica para fora... A borda parece não ocupar espaço na vertical, apenas na horizontal. Por que isso acontece?

**OBS:** eu não quero um jeitinho para resolver isso, eu sei que por exemplo colocando `display:inline-block` no `span` resolveria. O que eu quero saber é por que a Borda só ocupa espaço horizontal e não vertical, ela empurra o próximo elemento para o lado, mas no topo ela não empurra, e ainda fica para fora do *container*, pq?

```css
.container {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
span {
    border:10px solid red;
    /* display:inline; */
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
    <span>text</span><span>text</span>
</div>
<div class = "container">
    <span>text</span><br>
    <span>text</span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: acho que o `display` influencia, se usar `display: inline-block`, ele renderiza diferente

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim eu notei, inclusive já tinha até escrito na pergunta. Só não sei pq no display *default* ele afasta lateralmente e não verticalmente, essa é a dúvida.

Comment: O span é _inline_ por padrão, logo ele obedece à regra vertical da linha como se fosse um texto. Se vc converter ele em bloco, aí ele já não irá se comportar como se fosse um texto e irá se afastar verticalmente tb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `span` por ser um elemento *inline* por padrão, fica restrito à linha em que ele está, e não tem *poder* de influenciar (empurrar) elementos em outras linhas, apenas dentro da sua própria.

Como a borda aplicada irá ultrapassar para cima a para baixo da linha, ela apenas as *invade*, sem influenciar os elementos que lá estão, mas pode influenciar os elementos aos lados, pois estão na mesma linha. Isso diferencia basicamente os elementos em *bloco* e os *inline* (além de muitas outras diferenças), onde aqueles não ficam restritos à linha onde se localizam e *empurram* tudo que estiverem à volta, enquanto que estes só possuem influência dentro da sua linha.

Fiz uma pequena ilustração que mostra a borda do texto saindo da linha e invadindo as linhas de baixo e de cima, tal como ilustra o exemplo na pergunta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bacana jovem, parece que é por ai mesmo!